# Is there a method to edit the look of a javascript prompt?

Tags: javascript, prompt

Is there a method I can use to edit the look of a prompt on javascript?
Ive looked for some methods but they are confusing me

Comment: you mean `window.prompt`? no there is nothing you can do to change the look of the builtin prompt/alert etc - most programmers never use them anyway

Comment: @JaromandaX ok then

Comment: sweetalert is popular amongst some people